# I need some assistance with Makefile in my project

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to make a Makefile but I'm having some problems

first I have

2 source files: ~/main.c ~/lib/library.c
1 header file: ~/include/library.h

main.c and library.c both share the same header file library.h

```
# Compiler options
CC = gcc
INC = -I../include
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -c $(INC)
LIB = -L../lib
LFLAGS = -Wall -g $(LIB)

# Dependencies
LIBS = -libmylib
OBJS = main.o
SRCS = $(OBJS:.o=.c)
EXEC = a.out

# Other rules
RM = rm -rf
TAGS = tags
BAK = Makefile.bak

all: $(EXEC)
    @echo ------------------------ Compile Complete ----------------------------

.PHONY: clean depend

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(INC) -M $^
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *~ $(EXEC) $(TAGS) $(BAK)

depend: $(SRCS)
    makedepend $(INC) $^
```

it keeps saying that I it can't make a rule out of library.o

plus I have another question

I acknowledge the fact that when Makefile comes in to action after calling 'make',

and subsequently go to the line .c.o or %c: %o(in GNU enhanced version) and make

.o files. but why doesn't it also call clean and depend automatically?

---

I've edited some things from the previous version of Makefile

this time, (well pretty similar to the previous problem) even though I

clarified the library path(-I../lib),

the Makefile cannot find the archive file (which I created as libmylib.a in ../lib dir)

now it's driving me crazy

Comment: i've tried your makefile into my pc, it compile and i have a binary a.out

Comment: if you run `make` without specifying the target, by default the target `all` will be made. If you need to automatically clean everything after/before build (why do you want it?), add `clean` target to `all`, so it will look like `all: $(EXEC) clean`

Comment: @qrdl oh.. It's just curiosity~ I get it... but then why does .c.o go into action even it's not in the included in 'all'? is it just merely grammer??

Comment: @qrdl Technically, this is the first target of the `Makefile` (which is indeed `all` in this case) that is made.

Comment: In which directory does your Makefile live? Because, relative to `main.c`, your library is in `lib/library.a`, not in `../lib/library.a` (from the top of your question). Giving the path for main in your `Makefile`, `main.c` and `Makefile` are in the same directory, and your `$LIB` is wrong (should be `LIB = -Llib`). Unless you changed things and forgot to update your question.

Comment: Also, it's a typo: `LIBS = -libmylib` should be `LIBS = -lmylib` (unless the filename is really `liblibmylib.a`).

Comment: @Evert: don't you mean `libibmylib.a`?

Comment: @Christoph Eh, well yes. Typos everywhere I guess. Luckily, the fix remains the same.

Comment: `make` provides a lot of implicit rules (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) and you can take advantage of them if you follow the naming conventions.  (Also see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules for gnu make specifics).  In particular, you're breaking conventions with your names.  You should use `LDFLAGS` and `LDLIBS`.  See also https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html#Implicit-Variables

Answer (score 0):

> but why doesn't it also call clean and depend automatically?

Because `make` only builds the target you tell it. If you don't specify one, the first target is built, which in many cases, such as yours, is the 'all' target.